# what wrong with my binding convert?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I have some interface and class that contain List

```
public interface IListContain
{
    Int32 ItemCount
    {
        get;
    }
}

public class myStackPanel : StackPanel, IListContain
{

    ... // implimentation ... 
}
```

I want to do binding between some TextBlock and the variable that 'point' on the object instance myStackPanel - so i wrote is in this way

XAML:

```
                <TextBlock x:Name="ItemCount" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding ElementName=ListContainObject, Path=ItemCount,Converter={StaticResource IntConverter}}" />
```

The convert code ( int to string )

```
 public class IntToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{        
    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        return ( ( int )value ).ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        int result;
        var succes = int.TryParse( ( string )value, out result );
        return succes ? result : 0;
    }
}
```

And on the cs file of the xaml i define in the constructor the

```
      DataContext = this;
```

But still - nothing work !!! 
I dont have fire convert event !!!

And i dont know what i did wrong.

Please help ...

Thanks. 
( this code is in silverlight and the ListContainObject is not null ... its point on real object )

Comment: why you need an int to string converter? Int are converted to string automatically.

Comment: Ok , removing this convert also does not help me .. its still dont work

Comment: The converter is completely superfluous as the binding engine calls ToString on everything which isn't a string already anyways. Of course it does not help, your binding is probably broken

Comment: What XAML element is the `ListContainObject`? What is the code for `myStackPanel.ItemCount`?

Comment: Felicecs comment is true but might be worth keeping converter just for debug purposes - you can put a break point in it and verify that binding is happening (as you can verify at the moment that it is not!).  When all working go ahead and remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't say for sure without you showing us your implementation, but it's likely you've not used a dependency property for `ItemCount` / implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Thus, WPF has no idea when the property is changing and the UI won't update accordingly (nor will your redundant converter).

Comment: the imp. is simple - just return the count of the items

Answer (score 0):

Your using ElementName in your binding - this must resolve to the "name" field of an object listed in the xaml file - Im not sure from your code if thats the case.  For example if you had in your xaml a ListBox control with name="my_listbox" then it would be fine for your binding  to icnlude ElementName="my_listbox", but the way you describe it here Ive got a feeling your ListContainObject is declared somewhere in code behind?

Comment: yes, on the stackpanel i have ItemsControl - and the interface with the one method just return the count of the items.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a string converter when you bind an int sincer is done automatically. Probably your issue is that you don't have any element having `x:Name="ListContainObject"`